# calculated column in pivot table from power pivot

Tags: pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

From SQL server I have a query that gives me daily transaction numbers for few companies per day, something like

```
DATE          Company    Total    Tax year
2013-04-24    ABC         50       2013
2013-10-15    DEF         20       2014
```

And so on. This data goes nicely into power pivot and then to pivot table so I can show values per company per month/year

```
            2013      2014 
ABC 
January     600       750
Feb         800       900

DEF    
January     1000      750
Feb         900       110
```

Now, the simples thing I need is to add the DIFFERENCE column. But since the data is taken from the database, Excel treats it as an OLAP data and the option "Calculated field" in "Fields, items and sets" is greyed out.
I don't want simply paste the data from the database (which would be the easiest solution) since it would be nice to have this data live. Its such a trivial thing, yet I can't get with reasonable solution.

OK, I've found PARTIAL solution by creating additional pivot table and by displaying the difference based per year (instead of sums). This can be done by clicking on the new pivot chart, selecting "Show values as > Difference from and then selecting "Tax year" and "previous"

Answer (score 2):

You've almost got the solution - but you don't need to create a second pivot table.

Let's start from here - you've got your pivot table as described above, and now you're looking to add a **Difference** column.

[image]

Drag **Total** into the `Values` area a second time. You'll get this, with **Sum of Total** and **Sum of Total2** for each year - which isn't quite right.

[image]

In the `Values` section, swap **Tax Year** and **∑ Values** so that **∑ Values** is on top.

[image]

Now, as you worked out, right-click on your second column, and select `Show Values As` > `Difference From` and then select **Tax year** and **previous**.

[image]